# How to start hugo web server as daemon (service) on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, daemon, hugo

Hugo is mentioned as stable enough to run as web server in production.
I do not need more features than Hugo has, so for me it seems a good option.
But i can't find in documentation how to install it as daemon.
All related articles show how to run in in command line only.
(Ubuntu 16.04, if it is important)

Comment: You'll probably find better answers on https://serverfault.com/.  First find out if your server is using init.d, upstart or systemd then look at https://serverfault.com/questions/204695/comprehensive-guide-to-init-d-scripts, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84252/how-to-start-a-service-automatically-when-ubuntu-starts or https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers.

Comment: Hugo writes a set of plain .html pages which can be uploaded to a webserver to be fetched & displayed by a browser. It's not a webserver.  Are you confusing it with something like 'Caddy'?

Comment: @Alister: Hugo may perform as webserver, it is used for example for "debugging" (you edit source, hugo is monitoring changes, rebuilds it & shows updated version in browser). From official docs: Hugo provides its own webserver which builds and serves the site. While hugo server is high performance, it is a webserver with limited options. Many run it in production... https://gohugo.io/commands/hugo_server/
I would like to be one of those "many" who run it in production.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to be running Hugo as a web server. As others have commented, it is really only for development and debugging.

In fact, I've noticed that there are differences between running the server (on Windows) and the generated page outputs and these can catch you out. I also notice that redeploying a site with the server does not always clear out previous data which can also cause issues.

If you have access to a server capable of running Hugo, you certainly have the ability to run a web server such as Apache or NGINX. My person preference is for NGINX as it performs extremely well even on servers with restricted resources.

Using a proper server will also give you the ability to add standard security protections to your site. Helping prevent malicious actors from gaining access to the site content or server and providing security and privacy (via TLS for example) to your end users.